# PHPのエラーログに記載される時刻を日本時間表記にしたい（現況：Europe/Berlin）

Tags: php

標題の件、インターネット上の文献を参考に、php.iniのTimeZoneは変更済みですが、Europe/Berlin基準と思える時刻表記のままです。
誤った記事でも参考にしているのか、PHP　Ver7は別途の対策を要すのでしょうか？

お手すきの方、ご教示をよろしくお願い申し上げます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

php infoを今しがた確認した結果です。.iniと状況が違っている？？？ようなのですが、こういうことってありえるんですかね？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

おかしなことが起きているような．．．編集したiniファイルの所在パスを示しています。

Comment: 実行方法により確認方法は異なりますが、`php -i`(コマンドライン)や`phpinfo()`(関数)で読み込んでいる`php.ini`が編集しているものと一致しているか確認されたでしょうか? 確認結果があると何かわかるかもしれません。

Comment: user20098様　ご教示ありがとうございます。iniファイルしか確認していませんでした。本文にinfoのスクリーンショットを貼り付けました。こんなことって．．．．対策があると嬉しいのですが

Comment: 既に指摘されているように読み込んでいるphp.iniがそれと違う、or php.iniの変更後にサーバーを再起動(設定のリロード)出来ていないので反映されていない、とかでは？

Comment: phpinfo()の上の方に「Loaded Configuration File」など読み込んでいるphp.iniが表示されているはずなので変更したファイルとあっているか確認を。また環境はなんですか？XAMPPとかならApache(httpd)を再起動してみてください

Comment: 皆様　ご見解ありがとうございます。2箇所にTimeZoneが記載されていることを確認しました、お騒がせしました。今編集を終えたので確認してみます。

Comment: 直りました！重ねてお詫び申し上げます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

当案件は解決致しました。
コメントに記載したように、PHP.iniファイル中に2箇所にTimeZoneを記載してしまっている状況で、後方の記述が採用されてしまっている状況でした。
極めて初歩的なミスで、皆様のお手を煩わせてしまい大変申し訳ございませんでした。